# Sort order with 4 conditions that included geo_point and japanese characters by elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, elasticsearch-6, cjk

I have some documents of shops like below. How can i get query to:

1. Descending order of number_fans at shops
2. Descending order of number_articles at shops
3. Close from the current position order
4. Japanese alphabet order

Indexing data

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/shops/doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'  
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "中村 裕美子",
 "furigana_name": "木村 稔",
 "number_fans": 4,
 "number_articles": 1,
 "group_name": "有限会社 伊藤",
 "location": {
     "lat": 35.1284,
     "lon": 137.1446
     }
 }

curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/shops/doc/2" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'  
{
 "id": 2,
 "name": "山田 明美",
 "furigana_name": "木村 稔",
 "number_fans": 3,
 "number_articles": 2,
 "group_name": "有限会社 佐藤",
 "location": {
     "lat": 35.1177,
     "lon": 137.1915
     }
 }

curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/shops/doc/3" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'  
{
 "id": 3,
 "name": "松本 晃",
 "furigana_name": "松本 裕美子",
 "number_fans": 3,
 "number_articles": 3,
 "group_name": "株式会社 青山",
 "location": {
     "lat": 35.1098,
     "lon": 137.4242
     }
 }
```

This is my query but it is missing filter japanese alphabet characters order and not sure is correct order for other.

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/shops/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'  
{
"query": {
    "match_all" : {}
},
"sort": [
    { "number_fans": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "number_articles": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "_geo_distance" : {
            "location": {
                "lat": 35.13914,
                "lon": 137.18779
            },
            "order" : "desc",
            "unit" : "km"
        }
    }
],
"size": 200
}
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: Nobody can't help? :(

Answer (score 0):

For #4, you need to sort by furigana_name column, which supposed to have Japanese alphabets, Hiragana or Katakana.

Your sample data seems to be incorrect, as the furigana_name has another person's kanji name. For example, the first record's name "中村 裕美子" should have furigana_name "なかむら ゆみこ"(I am guessing pronunciation, could be wrong).

Comment: thank for answer. Yes, i'm using sample data that generate by faker factory.
I have research [kuromoji analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.0/analysis-kuromoji-analyzer.html) but i don't know which is correctly analyzer for filter japanese alphabet. Could you suggest something? i'm beginner elasticsearch

Comment: It is impossible. Kuromoji "guesses" katakana/hiragana from kanji, but it is not perfect and especially proper nouns tend to be wrong. The Faker factory seems not having the matched furigana generation. You need to prepare name and its right pronounces matched data from somewhere to test.

Comment: [Gimei](https://github.com/willnet/gimei) says that it is an alternative of the Faker which can generate correct furigana data.

Comment: So you mean that can't use Kuromoji analyzer in my case? just use basic query match?. Thank for suggestion lib to generate correct furigana data!

Comment: If you let Kuromoji "guess" katakana/hiragana of Faker generated (kanji) names, that guessed kana-s could be incorrect. Testing over incorrect data does not make sense. There is no way to get correct kana from kanji-only fields. That's why Japanese web form always ask users kana name along with kanji name.